# SQL date filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just a fairly general date filtering question...

I've got a date field that contains YYYYMMDD (no time).
When looking for transactions in the current month I get a different result if I do...

```
and MyDateField between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-31'
```

to if I do...

```
and Year(MyDateField) = '2017' and Month(MyDateField) = '3'
```

It looks like the 'between' method is excluding anything that happened on the 1st March (the other transactions are future dated).

Why is this?

These are the results from the 'between' method...

```
20170303
20170327
20170309
20170324
20170331
20170306
```

and these are the 'Year/Month' results...

```
20170303
20170327
20170309
20170324
20170301
20170331
20170306
20170301
```

The data is stored as an nvarchar(8) - should I be converting to date first?

Comment: Post your sample data and expected result.

Comment: Could you post some sample of how your date datatype looks like and its datatype

Comment: edited to show results

Comment: If it looks like a `DATE`, smells like a `DATE`, and quacks like a `DATE` - then yes, you **SHOULD** make that column a `DATE` datatype! ***ALWAYS***  use the most appropriate datatype - that's what they're there for! And storing a date into a string is **not** the most appropriate way to store this information.....

Comment: Well, your last sentece says it all. Don't store dates as strings, and you will save yourself from a lot of pain. Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Yep, that's it - unfortunately, it's coming from a badly designed proprietary system that stores a date as an nvarchar!

Answer (score 5):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive.

```
and MyDateField between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-31'
```

is the same as:

```
and MyDateField >= '2017-03-01' 
and MyDateField <= '2017-03-31'
```

The only explanation I have is that the type of `MyDateField` is **not** `date`, but `datetime` or something similar that **may** have a time component.

And some values in your table actually have this non-zero time component.

So, you query should look like this:

```
and MyDateField >= '20170301' 
and MyDateField < '20170401'
```

For more details see [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by Aaron Bertrand.

---

Well, after you said that the column type is `nvarchar(8)`, then it becomes obvious that comparison of **strings** '2017-03-01' and '20170301' can't lead to anything good.

When you use `BETWEEN`, you compare strings, not dates. When you use `YEAR` and `MONTH`, the server converts your `nvarchar(8)` values into dates behind the scene (and ruins performance).

---

You *may* store dates as `nvarchar(8)`, but then you need to compare them to the strings in the same format, like this (without dashes):

```
and MyDateField >= '20170301' 
and MyDateField <= '20170331'
```

It would be better to store them as `char(8)` and it would be significantly better to store them as `date`, though. 3 bytes for `date` vs. at least 17 bytes for `nvarchar(8)`.

See [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: Yep - nvarchar is the problem!